# Why does the value of c not change?

Tags: c, increment

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int a = 5, b = -7, c = 0, d;
    d = ++a && ++b || ++c;
    printf("\n %d,%d,%d,%d", a,  b, c, d);
}
```

In the above code, the output is 6,-6,0,1. Why is the value of c 0 and the value of d 1?
how did d get the value as 1?

Comment: See this: [Short Circuit Evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Answer (score 7):

That is because `||` first checks the left part and if it is true it return true without evaluating the right part.

In C any non zero is treated as True and zero as False

```
int a = 5, b = -7, c = 0, d;
    d = ++a && ++b || ++c;
```

Here ++a and ++b are non zero and both are treated as True so `++a&&++b` becomes True and the expression stops evaluating over there.

Answer (score 1):

There are already good answers that explain why `c` is `0` after the line

```
d = ++a && ++b || ++c;
```

is executed.

The line is equivalent to:

```
d = (++a && ++b || ++c);
```

That explains why `d` is `1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int a = 5, b = -7, c = 0, d;
d = ++a && ++b || ++c;
```

let's analyze the statement part by part

++a : a=6

++a && ++b: b becomes -6 ,and then it does : 6 && -6 ,which is equal to 1

now there is a || (or symbol) ,but this cannot affect the value of d since

`1||"value2" =1` ,
so the compiler does not evaluate "++c" .

so c remains 0 and d becomes 6 && -6 =1

Answer (score 0):

&& has higher precedence than || so first ++a&&++b is evaluated first and it becomes true. The expression becomes `true || ++c` and || will evaluate from left to right since `||` encounters true and it returns 1 to d without evaluating ++c. So c value will not be incremented

Answer (score 0):

An evaluation tree is created which does the evaluation. The || part is parent and the two parts on its side are its parents. When it evaluates one child, if it gets true, it doesn't evaluate the other child.